# firebase cloud messaging: setBackgroundMessageHandler not called

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am prototyping browser push notifications with FCM. I just copied the example code from the quickstart (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging). Messages are recieved and displayed as they should be. But when I try to modify the message in the Service Worker (messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler) nothing happens. The service worker is called, and if I implement an event listener in that service worker for the push notifications, it catches the event. But the method setBackgroundMessageHandler is never called. 
I am trying this on Chrome 54.

Any ideas what I need to do to customize the message in the service worker?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 51):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, here is the answer: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71

short summary: do not include a "notification" element in your json message.

Comment: This saved my life. I was literally going `crazier` trying to understand why my handler was not being called.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/messaging/src/controllers/sw-controller.ts

Comment: If I remove the "notification" then it supports fro web app. But it doesn't support for mobile Android and IOS. Any solution?

Comment: Same problem as @acmsohail.

Comment: @acmsohail did you find any solution?

Comment: @Adnan not yet.

Comment: ```setBackgroundMessageHandler``` and ```self.addEventListener('notificationclick')``` not working for firefox

Comment: I posted an answer above to work around this issue on web while maintaining support for native apps

Answer (score 10):

This is a solution that worked for me in a webapp. It displays the notification with title and body text along with an image and handles the user click.

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN',
  databaseURL: 'YOUR_DB_URL',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJ_ID',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_SENDER_ID',
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('Handling background message ', payload);

  return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    tag: payload.data.tag,
    data: payload.data.link,
  });
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(event.notification.data));
});
```

**JSON Message**

```json
{
  "message": {
    "token": "YOUR_TARGET_APP_TOKEN",
    "data": {
      "title": "FCM Message",
      "body": "This is an FCM Message",
      "icon": "https://shortcut-test2.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/role_image/attachment/10461/thumb_image.jpg",
      "link": "https://yourapp.com/somewhere"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Two years later they it still has this behaviour, you saved my life

Comment: Such JSON Message is invalid for for the **Legacy HTTP API**.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, including notification in the payload stops it working on the web JS SDK, however you need it present for it to work in native apps.

The workaround I found for the web was to use the web browser native EH `push` to handle the event manually:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onpush

```
  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('SW: Clicked notification', event)

    let data = event.notification.data

    event.notification.close()

    self.clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.link)
  })

  self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    let data = {}

    if (event.data) {
      data = event.data.json()
    }

    console.log('SW: Push received', data)

    if (data.notification && data.notification.title) {
      self.registration.showNotification(data.notification.title, {
        body: data.notification.body,
        icon: 'https://example.com/img/icons/icon-144x144.png',
        data
      })
    } else {
      console.log('SW: No notification payload, not showing notification')
    }
  })
```

Comment: For me neither messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler() nor messaging.onMessage() was getting called. With your workaround I finally got console messages upon receiving notification

Answer (score 3):

setBackgroundMessageHandler will be called always in both ios and android
In iOS, if app state is quit or killed
It is refreshed after few minutes.
Make sure to send content_available : true in the payload

```
{
     "registration_ids":["token"],
     "collapse_key" : "packageName",
     "notification" : {
         "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
         "title": "Title of Your Notification",
         "sound": "default"
     },
     "priority": "high",
     "content_available": true, // This is compulsory for background handler
     "data" : {
         "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
         "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
         "badge": 89
     }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks a ton. content_available makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to send a push message are you doing it while your app is on focus or not? Because from the documentation, it says that setBackgroundMessageHandler is only called when the *Web app is closed or not in browser focus*.

Based on the  example code from the quickstart (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging).

If your app is in focus: the push message is received via messaging.onMessage() on the index.html
If your app does not have focus : the push message is received via setBackgroundMessageHandler() on teh service worker file.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention this: on focus it works well and onMessage method is called and I can do what I want with the message. When the page has no focus, the notification is displayed but I cannot customize it within the setBackgroundMessageHandler method as it is never called.

Answer (score 0):

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
       console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
          });
```

This one fixed mine issue.