# Firebase messaging `setBackgroundMessageHandler` overrides notification body #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase, web-push, firebase-admin

I'm using the new `admin.messaging().sendToDevice()` method to send Web Push notifications. I'm sending both `notification` and `data` so I can show users some context in the message.

On client-side I'm using `firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler()` to handle receiving messages.

The problem is that the `setBackgroundMessageHandler()` never gets called. I tried the solution from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462414/firebase-cloud-messaging-setbackgroundmessagehandler-not-called) but if I alter the payload structure on the server to add the `notification` in the `data` field an error is thrown saying I should only use strings as values in the `data` (the `notification` is an object. see [admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload)).

If I don't use `firebase.messaging` on the server and just restructure as the other answer suggested, I won't be able to enjoy the wonderful feature of `clickAction` which saves me handling the `notificationclick` myself.

I also added listener to the `push` event on the service worker and I receive the full payload (both `notification` and `data` are available), it just doesn't call the callback

Is it a bug with `firebase.messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler()`? Or am I not using it how I'm supposed to?

Comment: Don't nest the `"notification"` key inside the `"data"` key. They should both be top-level keys and both are optional. So, try something like `sendToDevice(registrationToken, { notification: { title: 'Title' } })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Firebase support and they said that's the expected behavior.

So if one wants to do something when a `push` happens he should only send the `data` field. If a `notification` field is sent, it will take precedence and the callback won't be called but the user will get a notification.